# How to find the value of the key?

Tags: javascript, key

I have to find the key from this javascript.

```js
function generateKey() {
                var i = 1;
                var x = 64;
                var n = 5493;
                while (i <= 25) {
                    x = (x * i) % n;
                    i++;
                }
                key = "flag_" + Math.abs(x);
            }
            
            generateKey();
            
            // Encode the message using the 'key'
            function encode() {                                                        
                var input = $("#inputmessage").val();
                var output = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(input, key);
                $("#outputmessage").val(output);
            }
```

I'm confused by what function generatekey does.  Also does anyone know what "flag_" means.  Any help in figuring this out is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `flag_` is just a string, `abs(x)` is being concatenated with it to make a string like `flag_12345`.

Comment: `generateKey` is just doing simple arithmetic in a loop. What part of it is confusing you?

Comment: Thanks, I thought that flag did some kind of function, just being a string means it makes sense now.

Comment: Didn't you see the quotes around it? That makes it a string.